# Use dkim in phpmailer code with privacy key

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

I am using PHPMailer.

I added DKIM attributes when sending file.

The code is like:

```
// $mail is PHPMailer class
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "*******"; 
$mail->Port  = ***; 
$mail->Mailer= "SMTP";
//...
$mail->DKIM_domain = 'mydomain.com';
$mail->DKIM_identity = '@mydomain.com';

$mail->DKIM_private =  __DIR__ . '/privacy_key_mydomain.txt';
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'default';
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = ''; // only ssl.
//...
```

(Same as example on: [Send mail in phpmailer using DKIM Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463425/send-mail-in-phpmailer-using-dkim-keys))

When sending to email, such as mine (gmail), I have no problem, and I see that my email is signed by mydomain.com.

I see also, in the email source that DKIM-Signature is sent.

Nevertheless, some of my clients I am sending emails reject my email, with following message (especially for yahoo emails - more that 90% of rejects uses yahoo for their emails).

554 Message not allowed - Headers are not RFC compliant[291]

As I did some workaround, I found this message to be detected as a spam.

I am using CPANEL for my site, which has round-cube - so I test it at round-cube (sending the customer a message with round-cube) - seems OK. No spam detect.

So, I suspect the privacy key file may be incorrect (I have an SSL site - so I use the same privacy key as my own site).

What may be wrong? What shall I check out in order to avoid my emails will be detected as spams?

Here is the email source result:

```
Delivered-To: myaccount@gmail.com
Received: by 10.114.75.12 with SMTP id y12csp118366ldv;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 11:44:11 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.140.104.49 with SMTP id z46mr36090427qge.74.1405449850437;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 11:44:10 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <support@mydomain.com>
Received: from lin9.maindomain10.net (lin9.maindomain10.net. [1.2.3.4])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t14si21957304qac.66.2014.07.15.11.44.09
        for <myaccount@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 11:44:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.2.3.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=support@mydomain.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mydomain.com; s=default;
    h=Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:Reply-To:From:To:Date:Subject:To; bh=HBLjhR1eb0w5FQ9aVj60Gu0x3jP9XWQ7LQkpzTRHjfQ=;
    b=ECWMCs3iPsjuvlT473K9u3skwyNRVunmnv3p440Nk2ZJVrbuWoO0vgzaWM8gjCC503ADKivdfrrOek8TgTSEI7G4B3WMCHI50PWq68W5rcscYJqErWxuqAVcSl4r5tomk88AYPhHiotCugmRTjwQ2K/JBtHsAvMhTlVQMMXsMl0=;
Received: from mainuser by lin9.maindomain10.net with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <support@mydomain.com>)
    id 1X77hp-0001f9-SH; Tue, 15 Jul 2014 14:44:01 -0400
To: myName Mizrahi <myaccount@gmail.com>
Subject: Statistics from Sample Name site
Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 14:44:01 -0400
To: myName Mizrahi <myaccount@gmail.com>
From: "donotreply@mydomain.com" <root@localhost>
Reply-To: Sample Name site <donotreply@mydomain.com>
Subject: Statistics from Sample Name site
Message-ID: <d984a2c6308ef2a97cf6ccfe6292263a@mydomain.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - lin9.maindomain10.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [927 895] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mydomain.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: lin9.maindomain10.net: authenticated_id: mainuser/sender_address_domain
```

When sending message from round-cube, the email source look like this:

```
Delivered-To: myaccount@gmail.com
Received: by 10.114.75.12 with SMTP id y12csp118605ldv;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 11:48:53 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.224.161.129 with SMTP id r1mr34110372qax.86.1405450132678;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 11:48:52 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <support@mydomain.com>
Received: from lin9.maindomain10.net (lin9.maindomain10.net. [1.2.3.4])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id x8si13226659qas.81.2014.07.15.11.48.52
        for <myaccount@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 11:48:52 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.2.3.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mydomain.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=support@mydomain.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mydomain.com; s=default;
    h=Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version; bh=Bynm51C7RZD/vZ81iEMKjxxLoAJtSmKFcwU/eyFzPs8=;
    b=fUX+UKS9Ua0HK35AOBRBJbmqTEuKscCYAsPyxs3If3dhhvb/AvAjl1gR9Rz9AN0EX0mu275wtaN5Y1JWP+8w8VcGebJ9FEWsltCl9nwqL6bos/eEqJxTWjDG6ch9MHo3G0mSE326Pyc13JWa59InSgJyWi8MSstT1POfuEhfe28=;
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([127.0.0.1]:54911 helo=mydomain.com)
    by lin9.maindomain10.net with esmtpa (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <support@mydomain.com>)
    id 1X77mO-0001l7-1O
    for myaccount@gmail.com; Tue, 15 Jul 2014 14:48:44 -0400
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 14:48:43 -0400
From: support@mydomain.com
To: myaccount@gmail.com
Subject: test
Message-ID: <ed6307c2c9504e8ba9ec21f073d5f863@mydomain.com>
X-Sender: support@mydomain.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.9.5
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - lin9.maindomain10.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mydomain.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: lin9.maindomain10.net: authenticated_id: support@mydomain.com
```

Round-Cube works with no spam.
What is the main difference that's make the issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post an example message with headers? If your private key was wrong, it would not sign at all and verification on google would fail.

Comment: The privacy includes the 'public key' & 'private key' together (0A only as hexadecimal for new line).

Comment: That's what the clients get as dkim-signature (anything else?: DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; q=dns/txt; l=309; s=default;
 t=1405409881; c=relaxed/simple;
 h=From:To:Subject;
 d=mydomain.com; i=@mydomain.com;
 z=From:=20"donotreply@lmydomain.com"=20<root@localhost>
 |To:=20my20full20name<myemail@gmail.com>
 |Subject:=20test;
 bh=TsgRTSRyuHuPbbEhcGc2AZBcWYI=;
 b=QffG/IucUDzMEjbOZ05pOJ0SEx7KJ+bCk58hc7cSMmsrYpV7ChIZl2VA0ZfVxEtDMthLjgJvEmThnhiPGsQdKU8UWWaSEIisGLTZ/9lAom4mSvTfuQ7hc4IhfgBHZg6MU1gOP2XbHRgtWgUvU0Vkb6PAMjAB

Comment: Your private key should not be included anywhere in your message. Please post the whole message headers in the question - comment formatting isn't up to showing chunks of code like that.

Comment: I didn't understand - what did you mean of message with headers? The source is about 50 lines long.

Comment: You're complaining that the headers are being rejected and expecting us to be able to diagnose the problem without seeing them?? 50 lines is fine, you don't need to include the message body, and change any email adresses you don't want public.

Comment: Here are some more data (That's what you wanted?)                Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 06:20:01 -0400
To: My email <myemail@gmail.com>
From: "support@mysite.com" <root@localhost>
Reply-To: test site <donotreply@mydomain.com>
Subject: ****
Message-ID: <c10d0868062dc8bc2175f104c0cdbcdf@localhost.localdomain>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.2 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: And other data: Message-ID: <c10d0868062dc8bc2175f104c0cdbcdf@localhost.localdomain>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.2 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - *
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [927 895] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - *
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: *: authenticated_id:

Comment: As I said, comments are no use for posting large chunks of code - edit your question to add this info.
One obvious thing is that you are using an old version of PHPMailer - [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: OK, I put changes on my original question - you can check out, please. Thanks :)

Comment: That's better! I see you're still using the old version of PHPMailer. For some strange reason there are two sets of headers, including two DKIM signatures, in that message!!
I don't know if it's a copy/paste or line-wrapping issue, but those header lines are not correctly folded - I suspect it's a problem with getting it in here as it would not have passed DKIM validation otherwise. Make sure they are *exactly* as in the messaage you receive.

Comment: I see that there are two DKIM signatures - It is not mistake. That is the result of email source. I will use newer version for PHPMailer. Nevertheless, I don't know why there are two (perhaps the hosting provider put DKIM signature of their own). I put the signature as shown on my post (my code). How can I make sure that the DKIM is correct, and is there any way checking this out?

Comment: I suspect they are signing it - and two signatures is not going to work. While that might explain the DKIM signtures, the duplication of other headers (e.g. `To`) doesn't make much sense. If you send a message without signing, does it still arrive signed? Other than that, you should try sending through a different server in order to eliminate your ISP as a cause.

Comment: I am using CPANEL for my site, and in email -> email authentication I see that DKIM is enabled. I have checked when it is disabled, and I have realized that when it is enabled, it is automatically in the script (the DKIM-Signature with rsa-sha256 in mail source code). Also, I have realized that "To: " also appears twice. Nevertheless, I changed to newer PHP 5.2.4, and still got same spam detection error : Headers are not RFC compliant[291]. What shall I check next? Thanks :)

Comment: PHP 5.2.4 or PHPMailer 5.2.4? Both are pretty old. With the headers in that state I'm not surprised it's reporting that error, but I don't think it's PHPMailer that's causing it. It just sounds like Cpanel is making a right mess of your messages. I'm not really sure how to stop it - can you update cpanel, or not use it at all?

Comment: I meant PHPMailer 5.2.4, and I just downloaded it now from: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list. I changed my post, so you can see both Round-Cube mail script, and PHPMailer mail script. In Round-Cube it works with no spam detection. What make the main difference? If you say, I won't use phpmailer - so I won't. I realized that I need several parameters for PHPMailer to be set, i.e hostname should be (in order that message-id will be correct). Thanks :)

Comment: Why did you use that obsolete link when I gave you the up-to-date one? If the problem is happening inside a much larger system, you need to cut down the problem - take one of the simple PHPMailer examples and try that by itself. You have a far better chance of finding the problem if you reduce the number of places it can hide.
What you posted from roundcube looks correct. Something is coming between you and the PHPMailer output - it doesn't produce output like that by itself.

Comment: I didn't see the up-to-date one link you gave. Maybe I missed it. Can you sent it again. I tried to google it (https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=3xzGU--nMYaH4AbF1YGYDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=phpmailer+download) and didn't find new. Hopefully, this is the solution.

Comment: You're not trying very hard. It's the second result here: https://www.google.com/?#q=phpmailer and I linked to it in an earlier comment - all you had to do is scroll up: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: All the problem is that PHPMailer was on wrong version (I see that in the file it was version 5. and the old version is 5.2.4, but the year is 2014. That's was the problem. Now I have checked, and there are no spam detection, and the bug, that "To:" - I see only one recipient (as it should be. In old version - I see the same recipient duplicated). Problem solved. Thanks a lot! You can close this case.

Comment: Glad that fixed it. Since "update PHPMailer" was the solution, I've posted that as an answer, if you'd be so kind as to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.2.4 is pretty old and buggy - You need to update to the [latest PHPMailer from GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).