# Apply dkim when sending from x@domain1.com via domain2.com

Tags: php, email, smtp, spf, dkim

In mailchimp i am sending from my gmail account via mailchimp gateway, and the email is signed both spf and dkim. But i have my own smtp gateway, and when i send from a gmail or another email account via myserver.com only the spf is applied?

Ps: dkim is also applied but only if my send from email is on the same domain as the sending domain.

Any thoughts?

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce-mc.us7_22204859.801345-EMAILADDRESS=gmail.com@mail71.atl51.rsgsv.net designates 205.201.135.71 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce-mc.us7_22204859.801345-EMAILADDRESS=gmail.com@mail71.atl51.rsgsv.net;
dkim=pass header.i=@mail71.atl51.rsgsv.net
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you tagged php and phpmailer in your question.  If you are using phpmailer - phpmailer supports DKIM signing, and you can use it to add a DKIM signature for a message sent from any domain (provided of course that a DKIM record has been created in the DNS for that domain).  See [Send mail in phpmailer using DKIM Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463425/send-mail-in-phpmailer-using-dkim-keys) for an example.

Comment: In that case, you can create a message using phpmailer, use php mailer to add a DKIM signature to the message, then use phpmailer to send the message through your postfix MTA.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are trying to add a DKIM signature to a gmail address sent from yourdomain.com...

I don't think this is going to work, as yourdomain.com does not have the gmail private key to sign the message.