# How to install phpMailer in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: phpmailer

How to install `phpMailer` in a shared hosting environment? I need to use this for email verifications and password changing of the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download it here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Upload the folder to your server and include the main file with this line:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailerfolder/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
?>
```

After that, you will need an external SMTP account, like gmail.com for example. Here is a working example of PHPMailer with GMAIL:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailerfolder/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "youremail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
$mail->setFrom('youremail@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('to@site.com', 'To');

$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body    = "Message";

if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Error sending message";
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Make sure to enable "non secure apps" in this GMAIL account too: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: can I use the email account from the website? like `emailname@domainname.com` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use any SMTP you want, just replace the smtp.gmail with the smtp and information from your server.

Comment: btw, the installation process there is like composer? json? should I just ignore it and follow what you said?

Comment: The only installation process is to upload the files from github, there are nothing to do anymore after that.

Comment: Thanks, I will message you once I know the SMTP and  the port(they're support is off at the moment) and can I test this in `localhost` ?

Comment: Ok. I never tried in localhost but the PHPMailer uses a remote server to send messages, so, trying in localhost will probably work too.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but, it says that Gmail couldn't verify that website.com actually sent this message.

Comment: and I used this code, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial, because I do not know what will I type in `Username` & `Password`

Comment: I tried your code for gmail, error sending message.

Comment: Do you enabled your gmail account to allow less secure apps? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Yes it worked now, but when I tried it with my domain address, I saw this every time, `gmail couldn't verify that website.com actually sent this message (and not a spammer)`.

Comment: Oh, if you are going to use your domain, you will need to modify smtp.gmail to smtp.yourdomain, check with your host the configuration of: SMTP, SMTP Port (587 / 25 or other) authentication (yes or no), and inform all these in the script.

Comment: what do I type in `username` and `password`? my cPanel account?

Comment: No, you will put youremail@yourdomain.com and the password is the password to access this e-mail.

Comment: It worked but, there is still the red question mark appearing on the mail.

Comment: Have you changed the $mail->setFrom(''); to youremail@yourserver.com too? You will need to change this too, if yes, paste a print screen of imgur.com please.

Comment: Oh, I see. This looks like something related to DKIM, take a look here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/pqx8Wq_Csxw , this happens because Google made some changes to combat spam.

Comment: You need to implement DKIM and SPF to validate your domain for Google and other services, you can find how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463425/send-mail-in-phpmailer-using-dkim-keys

Comment: Where can I get a key?

Comment: I don't know, I never used PHPMailer with a custom domain name, I use only with gmail. You will need to check the DKIM with your host, the SPF records you can see in the DNS zone or Cloudflare (if your domain is on Cloudflare).

Comment: Thanks @bruno, I will find it.

Comment: I can't find PHPMailerAutoload.php in the version 6.x zip download, I assume because this file is meant to be created by composer. However if I run composer with the composer.json present there are 7 dependancies in the require-dev section - is there an easier installation on a shared host available?