# DKIM Signature not get verified (no key for signature)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, dkim

I had added a dkim txt record in my domain, it works fine.
[image]

I had added the signature in my email using phpMaier library but when the email goes to Gmail and I inspected that dkim verification failed. Can you help with that? Also, I didn't explicitly set up any SPF and dmarc records.

```
// sign
$mail->DKIM_domain = 'redravian.com';
$mail->DKIM_private = __DIR__.'/key.private';
$mail->DKIM_selector = '1636290028.redravian';
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = ''; //key is not encrypted
```

It's getting the following errors:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your keys must not be matching. Did you generate the public and private keys using sha256? This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463425/send-mail-in-phpmailer-using-dkim-keys/24464694

Comment: Also notice that your domain doesn't have a tls/ssl cert yet. That will likely cause issues too. Use Letsencrypt and get it setup with https first and try again..